# I want to scrape all the elements with the class image-reg, but, its not working when using phantomjs

Tags: node.js, web, web-scraping, phantomjs

```
 const request = require('request-promise');
 const cheerio = require('cheerio');


const url = 'https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780470458211-elementary-linear-algebra-tenth-edition/9/exercises/1/';
 var phantom = require('phantom');
   var _ph, _page, _outObj;

phantom
 .create()
 .then(ph => {
  _ph = ph;
return _ph.createPage();
})
.then(page => {
_page = page;
return _page.open('https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780470432051-elementary-linear-algebra-applications-version-tenth-edition/9/exercises/1/');
})
.then(status => {
console.log(status);
return _page.property('content');
})
  .then(content => {

  let $ = cheerio.load(content);
    var text = $('.image-reg');
    console.log(text);


_page.close();
_ph.exit();
  })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Guide me What Can I Do here, Actually I want to get the src attribute of class image-reg but when i look at its source code its not in source code too.

Comment: I haven't seen a phantomjs question in a while. Everyone else has switched to puppeteer.

Comment: Pupeteer can do that¿